# Deny selecting other tabpage when particular condition is false

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

I have two pages in a tab control, i wanted to restrict access to page to when check box is checked,please any one tell me how to do it in windows form application in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have this event **'Selecting'**  in the tabControl
As [MSDN docs states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting.aspx) you could prevent the tabpage change in this event verifying the *Checked* property of you checkbox

```
private void TabControl1_Selecting(Object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) 
{
    if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible with other controls,for example when one checkBox is checked,should not able to change another checkbox changed event???How can i do this have any idea??